# playframework limit upload file size and programmatically catch error

Tags: jboss, playframework, playframework-2.0

How to limit the file upload ? like php's upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.
I also want to capture the resulting error myself, so that i can show the page again with a msg like "Too Big File, max allowed is X MB"

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in the application configuration:

parsers.text.maxLength = (size) k

You can change the 413 Request Entity Too Large response by applying play.avi.mvc.Results.EntityTooLarge

EntityTooLarge([Some Message])